# How to increment correctly number for new folders, which have 2 files each inside

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, logic

This logic I would like to have:

user have to upload at least 2 different files. He can upload more than 2. But next pair of files have to be saved in another folder. I don't know how many files will be uploaded. But goal is to devide each pair of files into different folders.

My code works fine, but it creates folder #1, saves 2 files in it. Then creates folder #2 and saves all next files in this folder. But in folder #2 have to be only 2 files (like in folder #1), next pair of files have to be saved in folder #3 and so on, but next folder will not be created. Why so? My code:

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
private $folderId;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->folderId = 1;
}

/**
 * File Upload.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path = 'public/' . $this->folderId;
    $files = Storage::files($path);
    $filesSum = count($files);
    if ($filesSum <= 1) {
        $request->file('file')->storeAs($path, $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    } else {       
        $path = 'public/' . ($this->folderId + 1) ;
        $request->file('file')->storeAs($path, $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'File has been uploaded!');

}
```

}

Comment: why downvoting ?

Comment: in each request how many files you send ?

Comment: It looks like you aren't incrementing `$this->folderId` for subsequent calls.  You are adding 1 to 1 each time.  Does it work if you change `$this->folderId + 1` to `++$this->folderId`?

Comment: User sends 1 file in each request.
++$this->folderId  this didn't work also. It creates First folder, puts inside 2 files. Then creates second folder puts 2 files inside and continues to put next files in folder #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, if the file count in the folder '1' is greater than 1, it always uploads to the folder '2' & `folderId` never get incremented as you upload more files. You need to check the uploaded files to decide the `folderId`. Modify your code as,

```
/**
 * File Upload.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $uploaded_files = array_filter(Storage::allFiles('public'), function($file){
        // ignore the .gitgnore from the upoloaded list. You can improve this.
        return strpos($file, '.gitignore') === false;
    });

    $uploaded_files_count = count($uploaded_files);
    // intdiv() is supported from php7
    $folderId = intdiv($uploaded_files_count, 2) + 1;

    $path = 'public/' . $folderId;
    $files = Storage::files($path);
    $filesSum = count($files);

    if ($filesSum <= 1) {
        $request->file('file')->storeAs($path, $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    } else {
        $path = 'public/' . ($folderId + 1) ;
        $request->file('file')->storeAs($path, $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'File has been uploaded!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Iljas, that worked perfectly correct!! :)
Upvote from me for your answer!